# Unity webplayer wont work

Tags: unity, software-installation, pipelight

I tried using pipelight but I can't get unity to work for me.
I open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

Then, I type:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
```

I then get this error message:

```
sudo: pipelight-plugin: command not found
```

What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Unity3d only works on Firefox with pipelight, Chromium no longer supports the Netscape Plugin Api, which pipelight needs.  In fact, Unity3d doesn't run on Chromium for Windows either.

The Unity javascript component (which may be embeded in your sites javascript sources) looks for the 'navigator.platform' value of your browser to contain either 'win' or 'mac'. Since no user agent spoofer for Firefox does this (I use 'User Agent Overrider 0.2.5 on Firefox 38 on Ubuntu 14.04.2),  you must set your own override yourself.

Type 'about:config' in the Firefox address bar, get past the warnings and right click on the list of key-value pairs to creat a new string called 'general.platform.override' and set the value to 'Windows'

Here is the link to the test demo recommended by the pipelight maintainers

http://unity3d.com/showcase/live-demos#tropical-paradise

Be sure to run pipelight-plugin --system-check first to see if OpenGl is working correctly.  if you see 'llvmpipe' as the OpenGl renderer, you will have a terrible framerate as xorg will be using software 3d instead of hardware. In my case it was because of a problem with xorg.conf.  Disabling xorg.conf fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found:

## Links

### Pipelight

- [Ubuntu Pipelight Installation](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html)
- [User Agent Installation](http://pipelight.net/cms/installation-user-agent.html)
- [Unity Web Player With Pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/plugin-unity-webplayer.html)

### Unity 3D

- [Running Unity 3D ON Linux Using Pipelight](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Running_Unity_Web_Player_on_Linux_using_Pipelight)

## Commands

### Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

### Updating Web Player

```
#!/bin/bash

#FDS-Team: Pipelight Project
#Tomasz Zackiewicz, Pipelight.sh


#update the checksum of Unity3D Web Player
sudo pipelight-plugin --update

#for Firefox, clear the plugin cache
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins

#enabling Unity3D Web Player
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
```

### Enabling Plugin

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
```

### Instructions

1. First, install `pipelight-plugin`.
2. Second, enable the plugin `unity3d` using the command above.
3. Next, follow the user agent overrider instructions at the link above.
4. You're done!
5. If it doesn't work, please tell me.

Comment: I enabled unity, install it as well. However i cant open unity applications